# Extract a substring in a column in the 5th place - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, string, select, text-extraction

How can I extract a string that appears after 4 ';' in a column in a table using a select query?

For example - if U have the following value in the column:

```
1234;0000;567;655;0541234567;777;777
```

I would like to fetch the value in the 5th place; in this example it's

```
0541234567
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a bit of JSON

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol varchar(100))
Insert into @YourTable values ('1234;0000;567;655;0541234567;777;777')


Select A.SomeCol
      ,Val5 = JSON_VALUE(S,'$[4]')
 from @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values ( '["'+replace(SomeCol,';','","')+'"]' ) ) B(S)
```

**Returns**

```
SomeCol                                 Val5
1234;0000;567;655;0541234567;777;777    0541234567
```

EDIT -- CROSS APPLY not necessary if only after ONE value

```
Select A.SomeCol
      ,Val5 = JSON_VALUE('["'+replace(SomeCol,';','","')+'"]','$[4]')
 from @YourTable A
```

Comment: Can you explain what is happening here please?

Comment: @FriendlyManCub The CROSS APPLY will convert your delimited string into a JSON array.  Then we simply grab the appropriate index value.   To be clear, the {at}Yourtable is just a demonstrative table variable.   Also, if you not 2016+, there is a similar XML approach